# Strange exception opening new SSMS query window

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I see this exception each time I try to open a new SQL Server Management Studio Query window, or right click any user object to **modify**, **view** or **generate script**:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow,
>   Version=4.5.24.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting)

I have uninstalled and re-installed SSME 2017.3 and even upgraded to SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition all in a bid to fix this error, none has worked.

The exception details are as follows:

```
===================================

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.24.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.<CreateAssemblyCatalogsAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.CreateAssemblyCatalogsAsync(IReadOnlyCollection`1 assemblyPaths, IProgress`1 progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.<GetCurrentAssemblyCatalogsAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.<GetExportProviderFactoryAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.<GetMEFV3ExportProviderInternalAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.<GetMEFV3ExportProviderWrapperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run[T](Func`1 asyncMethod, JoinableTaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run[T](Func`1 asyncMethod)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetLazyValue[T](AsyncLazy`1 lazy)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetService[T]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorParts.get_ContentTypeRegistryService()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.LanguageServiceToContentTypeMapper.MakeLanguageServiceContentTypes(SettingsStore settingsStore)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.LanguageServiceToContentTypeMapper.InitLanguageServiceToContentTypeMapper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextDocData.SetSite(Object pUnkSite)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextBuffer.SetSite(Object serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextEditorControl.CreateAndInitTextBuffer(Object sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptEditorControl.Initialize(Object sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptAndResultsEditorControl.Initialize(Object sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.SqlScriptEditorControl.Initialize(Object sp, String moniker)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.SqlScriptEditorControl.CreateInstance(Object serviceProvider, Boolean withEncoding, String moniker)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.EditorFactorySql.CreateEditorInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean storeActiveConnIfNeeded, String moniker)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.EditorFactoryBase.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsEditorFactory.CreateEditorInstance(UInt32 createFlags, String moniker, String physicalView, IVsHierarchy hierarchy, UInt32 itemId, IntPtr existingDocData, IntPtr& docViewIntPtr, IntPtr& docDataIntPtr, String& caption, Guid& cmdUIGuid, Int32& result)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String strFullPathToScript, IVsProject projectToAddScriptTo, UIConnectionGroupInfo connectionInfoList, IDbConnection liveCon, String rootName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String strFullPathToScript, IVsExternalFilesManager extFileMgr, UIConnectionGroupInfo connectionInfoList, IDbConnection liveCon, String rootName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String strFullPathToScript, UIConnectionGroupInfo connectionInfoList, IDbConnection liveCon, String fileRoot)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String strFullPathToScript, UIConnectionInfo ci, IDbConnection liveCon)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.OpenFileInEditor(String filePath, IManagedConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.ScriptToQueryEditor(String text, IManagedConnection mc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.ScriptExistingTextObjectToWindow(IManagedConnection mc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.InvokeTextObject(IManagedConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.Invoke()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to repair your Visual Studio (if it installed)?

Comment: @RuslanK. I have VS2017 community edition, i'm just doing the 2017 15.4.0 update as we speak. the 2017 15.3.0 update did not fix this.

Comment: Did you have file `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll`? And what version it have?

Comment: no, i only have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community`

Comment: I don't have enterprise or standard at all, only community

Comment: I have : `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\System.Threading.Tasks.Da‌​taflow.dll` version **4.5.24.0**

Comment: I have 9 files with name `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` on my disk C. Another one `c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0\lib\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` (version 4.5.24.0). Maybe you can solve your problem on this way..

Comment: Thanks, I will clone into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7` folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156660/discussion-between-ruslan-k-and-charles-okwuagwu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to repair Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)